# Can't use ssh in a VM Centos

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, samba, centos6.5

When I tried to connect my Ubuntu 13.10 to my VM Centos 6.5 using ssh appear the message "Connection refused" or "No route to host" even than I change the port, noting change. [See here](http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_de_2014-04-03_18_37_48-png)

I need to use SSH, VPN and Samba, but this IP in my VM Centos do not work.

How Can I resolve this problem?